# Creating an extra slice in pie chart in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a SQL which counts the number of rows. Say the result is 80.

I would like to have a parameter that is user-input, to be the total. Lets say the user enters 100.

How would I use the two numbers, 80 and 100, to create a pie chart that shows the data takes up 80% of the total?

I cannot find a way to add custom slice in a pie chart in Crystal Report, is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to stick your SQL in a stored procedure then pass the crystal parameter to the sproc to generate the "dummy" slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple items to your chart.

Create a formula that calculates the difference between your measured value and your total. In your case this would be `total_rows_entered_by_user - number_of_rows`. Add the `number of rows` and the formula to the chart:

[image]